# Anime where guy breaks anything he touches

Tags: story-identification, anime, magic

I saw this in an anime years ago and I don't believe this was the main character of the show. But this one character broke/ deteriorated anything he touched. So when he fought he carried around a lot of swords to fight with.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you see this?  Approximately what year is "years ago?"

Comment: The main character of Goblin Slayer? It's not that he corrodes things; it's the goblin blood and guts that do. So he goes through a lot of blades